# Linux: Using find and grep to find a keyword in files and count occurrences

Tags: find, search-engine, wc

I'm using executing this bash commands inside a search script I've built with php:

```
find myFolder -type f -exec grep -r KEYWORD {} + 

find myFolder -type f -exec grep -r KEYWORD {} + | wc -l

find myFolder -type f | wc -l
```

The first line gives me back the filenames where KEYWORD was found.

The second line gives me the number of occurrences and the third line the total number of files.

Is there a way to do this more elegantly and faster?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get more efficiency if you avoid `-exec`, which makes one `fork` per file match. `xargs` is a better choice here. So I would do something like this:

```
find myFolder -type f -print0 | xargs -0 grep KEYWORD

find myFolder -type f -print0 | xargs -0 grep KEYWORD | wc -l
```

The last one should be OK, at least with GNU find.

The `-print0` and `-0` ensure that filenames with spaces in them are handled correctly.

Note that grep -r` implies recursive grepping, but as you're only supplying one filename in each invocation it is redundant.

Comment: To even more reduce computing cost, one can utilise Unix' "tee" to append the wordcount at the end of the outpout: "find myFolder -type f -print0 | xargs -0 grep KEYWORD | tee /dev/tty | wc -l"

Comment: I think `... | tee >(wc -l > match_count)` would work better, as the match list would still be available in the pipe. It isn't with `/dev/tty`.